# An object is placed in front of a plane mirror of length $L$ ...

Tags: euclidean-geometry

I am stuck on the following problem :

> An object is placed in front of a plane mirror of length $L$ at a distance $d$ of its bisector line .An observer is at a perpendicular distance of $2d$ from the mirror.If the observer is walking parallel to the mirror ,upto what maximum possible distance he can observe the image of that object . The options are
>
> (a) $2L\,$ (b) $\,3L\,$ (c)$\,4L\,$(d)$\,5L\,$

Can someone please explain ?

Comment: image is formed when two light rays meet ,now you can easily form an expression to solve the problem

Comment: is it $3L$ ie option b

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are diagrams of what's going on:

[image]

[image]

You can work out how long the line at the bottom is by comparing the big triangle with the little triangle.  They are similar triangles.